# JavaFx submenu not following web page

Tags: java, browser, position, javafx, submenu

I have made JavaFx menu and its submenus; they work fine in a stand-alone mode.

But if I embed them in the browser, its submenu is always stays in the first place where it is opened even after I dragged the browser (IE 9, Firefox latest) around desktop. Only the menubar is well re-located/dragged but its submenu is opened in its first place forever.

Here is the code:

```
    primaryStage.setTitle("Testing");
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(), 550, 250);
    MenuBar menubar = new MenuBar();

    //File menu
    Menu menu = new Menu("File");
    menu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("New"));
    menu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Save"));
    menu.getItems().add(new SeparatorMenuItem());
    menu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Exit"));

    Menu tools = new Menu("Tools");
    final MenuItem settingMenu = new MenuItem("Setting");
    tools.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Setting"));
    tools.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Network configuration"));
    tools.getItems().add(new MenuItem("File reader")); 

    Menu acq = new Menu("Actions");
    acq.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Start"));
    acq.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Stop"));

    menubar.getMenus().addAll(menu, tools, acq);        
    ((VBox) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(menubar);
    menubar.prefWidthProperty().bind(primaryStage.widthProperty());
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
```

Did I miss something? How to attach sub-menu to menubar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was told something in JavaFX forum. It is a bug. This has been reported to the Oracle and they will release the update version of JavaFX 2.1 later.